# Default positioning of parent DIVs is being ignored

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm a newbie in CSS layout. I need to display content like this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|                            Content_A|
| Content_B Content_C ...             |
+-------------------------------------+
```

I want a very simple markup and CSS, so I made this:

```
<div>
  <div id="d1">
    <div style="float: right;">Content_A</div>
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    <div style="float: left;">Content_B</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Content_C</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the result is this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| Content_B Content_C ...    Content_A|
+-------------------------------------+
```

Looks like default positioning of DIVs d1 and d2 is being ignored. Why and what's the solution?

If you have another markup/CSS suggestion for mentioned required layout (using SPAN for example), it will be welcome.

By the way, I mixed HTML and CSS just to make this problem easier to understand. In the real page, they will be separated!

Comment: @user507078 @faraz Thanks for the quick answers, I will use "display: table" and it was good to learn "text-align: right". Now for matter of better understanding, I'm still looking for an explanation for the unexpected result!

Comment: You need a better understanding of CSS Floats, That's why the result is not what you expect. Remember that if you really want to understand something, the best way is to try and explain it to someone else.

Comment: When I tested with "display: table;", I guess it worked because there was "text-align: right;" together. Now I've tested with "display: table;" alone and didn't work, so I'll use only "text-align: right;". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<div>
  <div id="d1">
    <div style="text-align: right;">Content_A</div>
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    <div style="float: left;">Content_B</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Content_C</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works for you or if you still have problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set display format for outer-most div to align the contents vertically:

```
<div style="display: table;">
  <div id="d1">
    <div style="float: right;">Content_A</div>
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    <div style="float: left;">Content_B</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Content_C</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution doesn't produce the desired results. Content_A, Content_B and Content_C are all on the same line. Check the requirements.

Comment: @Hasan: which browser are you testing this in? It should work in most modern browsers  (IE7 doesn't support it, IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE to support "table" display property). I just tested in in Chrome myself.

Comment: @Hasan: I'm not sure why your Chrome is producing different results from mine. Does specifying that property do anything at all? What about also setting `display: table-row;` for divs with ids d1 and d2?

Comment: It still doesn't work. Anyways check the solution that I've suggested. Hopefully it should work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
  <div id="d1">
    <div style="float: right;">Content_A</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="d2">
    <div style="float: left;">Content_B</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Content_C</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The clear property is a way of saying "make sure this element does not run alongside a previous float". Without having an element with clear, all later content on the page would attempt to flow alongside the columns. You could say that we're telling the browser, "the floats end here".

Check this [link](http://www.elated.com/articles/css-floats/) for more information.